# Activity Navigation is taking lot of time

Tags: android

Friends I am using intent to navigate from one activity to another.How ever the navigation process is taking about a minute.Please find logs

```
08-21 18:01:32.719: I/System.out(4636): Button has been clicked
08-21 18:02:32.999: I/System.out(4636): successfull navigation
```

Code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
if(v==refreshButton)
{
    System.out.println("Button has been clicked");
    startActivity(new Intent(this,Refresh.class));
}
```

Please help me in the same. I have tried cleaning the project and restarted the smartphone also.

Refresh Class

```
public class RefreshSettings extends Activity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener
{

    Button refresh;
    EditText code;
    String pinCode;
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager;
     String imei;
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        System.out.println("successfull navigation");
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        setContentView(R.layout.refresh_settings);


        telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        imei=telephonyManager.getDeviceId();

        refresh=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_Refresh_Settings);
        refresh.setOnClickListener(this);

        code=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext_Refresh_Code);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think there is long process or any long calculation in Refresh Class . Show Code of Refresh Class . Use thread or AsyncTask if there is long calculation

Comment: Check the `onCreate()` and `onStart()`-methods of the `Refresh`-Activity. If they take to much time, put some work in AsyncThreads.

Comment: hey mates codes have been added. 
@LukasKnuth can you please post the code here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `onSaveInstanceState()` to `onCreate()` .

From the documentation I understand that onSaveInstanceState() should be called to store only temporary information,

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    System.out.println("successfull navigation");
    setContentView(R.layout.refresh_settings);


    telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    imei=telephonyManager.getDeviceId();

    refresh=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_Refresh_Settings);
    refresh.setOnClickListener(this);

    code=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext_Refresh_Code);

}
```

Comment: `onSaveInstanceState()` is called by the system (not you) when the Activity instance will be destroyed - either because a new one is created (e.g. when you rotate the screen) or because you navigated away from the activity (e.g. press home button) and it is possible for you to come back to this activity. You can use this to save all the data that is required to recreate the Activity in about the state where you left it.